# What are the priorities of blood group that a person with AB group can recieve?

Tags: hematology, blood-group

Suppose a person has a blood group of AB. I read somewhere that it is best to transfuse blood of type AB into that person, as opposed to groups A, B, or O. If AB is not available, however, it might be better to use types A or B than O. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Blood groups are nothing but the classification of Red Blood Cells based on what particular molecules they have on their surfaces. A person with an A blood group has an A antigen (think of it as a protein) on the surfaces of their blood cells, while a person with a B blood group has a B antigen. People with AB have both the antigens, and people with O have none. The immune system produces certain antibodies that helps protect the body against foreign invaders. An antibody is a substance that helps kill foreign antigens. An antibody in a healthy individual will not attack the body's native cells. Thus, people with an A blood group only have anti-B antibodies, and vice versa. O people have both the antibodies and AB people have none.

[image: Blood groups]

This means that if a type A person receives type B blood, the newly introduced blood cells will be destroyed, due to the presence of anti-B antigens. Similarly a person with O cannot receive AB blood due to the presence of both antibodies in their plasma. However, AB people can receive any blood type, since they have no antibodies in their plasma. O people can ***donate*** to anyone, since they have no antigens in their RBC, but they can only receive donations from other O people.

[image: Blood donations]

This is why people with an O blood group are known as universal donors and people with an AB blood group are known as universal receivers.

A similar effect occurs with the Rhesus Blood Groups (+ve and -ve), where Rh+ people can receive either type, but Rh- people can only receive Rh- blood. Thus, Rh- can donate to either type, and Rh+ can receive either type. This means that O- can donate to any blood type, and AB+ can receive any blood type.

In terms of your question, suppose that a person with blood type AB needs to receive a blood transfusion. As explained above, a person with AB can only receive blood of type AB. This is why it's the "highest priority" to use blood of type AB. Although not medically recommended, A or B type blood has a better chance of compatibility with the receiver than type O, since type O has both the antibodies while type A or B only have one. Thus, the AB has the "highest priority" with type A or B having more "priority" than type O.

Hope this answer made things clear. Cheers!

Comment: Well illustrated answer - I think what the OP meant with _'priority'_ can be explained in the following scenario: Let's say you have a certain amount of 500 ml blood of each of the four types, the types should be prioriticed according to the [blood type distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_type_distribution_by_country) of that country and the donor/receiver ratio - a simple mathematical formular based on availability and the blood type distribution of possible receivers in need. But that's just my assumption..

Comment: I read the question, and I think I understand what the OP meant. Suppose a person has a blood group of AB. When transfusing blood to that individual, it is best to use blood of type AB. If AB is not available, A or B might be better to use than O. I don't think it's recommended to use anything other than AB though. Perhaps it's worth a try if the condition is critical and no AB blood is available.